# DIY project - Listen to Guitar Amp on a USB headset

Tags: usb, audio, adc

I have a Fender mustang GT40 which has a 3.5mm female audio jack connector so that the audio from the amp goes only to the headphones (crucial for me since I live in an apartment). It works wonders but I would really love to be able to connect my main headset to it.
My main headset is a Razer Kraken Ultimate, it's connected via USB, it has a couple of extra features but I don't care for those to be available when I'm connected to the amp.

Is it possible to make a Female-USB to Male-3.5mm Audio Jack connector out of some disposable headphones and a USB F-M extender?
I'm guessing so since there are a couple of those available in the market but most come around €5+ and that's a bit much for something so "simple".

Comment: It's not so simple. USB is digital, audio jacks are analog.

Comment: @JohnDoty It is not so simple like you said. This specific headset might be digital, but USB-C on phones can output analog audio to analog headset. So USB is not only digital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is not a simple wiring hack.

The Kraken USB headset, from the USB point of view, is a *digital* device. In fact the Kraken has a DAC in it. For it to work, it needs a digital stream from the upstream device (e.g. a PC or a phone). A direct analog connection won't work.

The thing you're asking for, 3.5mm phono to USB, would need to digitize the phono jack signal, then format it for USB to send on to the Kraken USB DAC. There's a lot involved in making that happen.

The headphone 'extender' you're talking about seems like it's a USB DAC with a 3.5mm jack port. That's the opposite of what you need, which would be an ADC, plus a USB-to-USB middleman of some sort.

Not exactly the cheap-and-cheerful solution you were thinking, yes? Seems like it would be less hassle to just get a set of analog phones to work with your amp.

Comment: From your description, yeah, not as cheap and simple as i thought... But i guess that it would be a fun project after all... So let me get this straight...
3.5mm jack into a ADC chip (poperly wired up obviously), connect that to a female USB cable and voilá? something like a MCP3008 would suffice?

Comment: @PedroCosta Is MCP3008 an **audio ADC** with **USB interface**? If not, then no.